# Wave Dashboard can't be retrieved - CLI error is not understandable

Tags: metadata, salesforcedx-cli, einstein-analytics

We are trying to retrieve WaveDashboard components with the sfdx cli.

The response from the CLI when using `sfdx force:source:retrieve -m WaveDashboard` is the following:

```
{
   "status":0,
   "result":{
      "inboundFiles":[
         {
            "fullName":"",
            "type":"",
            "problemType":"Error",
            "state":"Failed",
            "error":"Unable to retrieve file for id 0FK******** of type WaveDashboard. Dashboard state conversion failed: null"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I don't understand what this error is about - also why a record of type 0FK (WaveLens) is referenced. We tried to play around also retrieving WaveLens without any change in the result.

We did not have any problems by running the exact same command in the past, but for the specific org I always get this error. Unfortunately I can't isolate the problem as I don't know which dashboard causes the problem as there are multiple errors with the same kind of message on the result.

Any thoughts on this error or on how I could isolate the component would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What is the version you are using in the package.xml? Thanks

Comment: In our test we did not specify any specific api version in the CLI. The sfdx-project.json specifies "sourceApiVersion": "55.0"

Comment: Please change the parameter "sourceApiVersion": "55.0" to "57.0" . I've seen scenarios wherein changing this fixed the issue. Thanks

Comment: Thank you Swetha - this solved the issue! Would you mind to write this in an answer so I can accept it? Thank you!

Comment: So glad to know @Christian Menzinger :) I've posted this as an answer so it can help others in future. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sumarizing the solution from comments section:Based on similar scenarios I've seen, updating the sourceApiVersion in sfdx-project.json should fix the issue.

Steps:

1. Go to SFDX project folder and open the sfdx-project JSON file.
2. Change the parameter `"sourceApiVersion": "55.0"` to  `"sourceApiVersion": "57.0"`
3. Save the file and retry the retrieval again after auth.